# How to iterate the contents of one array into the empty/undefined spots of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I have an array:

`var myArray = [2, 4, 6];`

and another array:

`var otherArray = [1, , 3, , 5, , 7];`

I'm trying to map (or use any non "for/for-each" iterator) to place each `myArray` value into the corresponding empty spaces of `otherArray`.

Hopeful output:

`newArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those numbers significant?

Comment: Not at all, just examples

Comment: I simply need not use for/for-each

Comment: Why you don't want for-loop? What can you use instead ? While ? Recursion ?

Comment: Because I am working on a problem that requires I only use 1 forloop and I have already used it, and needed to.

Comment: I included a while loop in my answer, if that's an option. Edit: Also, if the requirements are specifically one "for" loop, forEach should still be an option. It is a function, just the same as .map is.

Comment: You might reconsider the accepted answer, none of the codes shared actually work.

Comment: Edited to include an example that will work for unset array values.

Answer (score 4):

```
otherArray.forEach(function (val, idx) {
    if (typeof val === 'undefined') {
        otherArray[idx] = myArray.shift();
    }
});
```

`forEach` may not be compatible if supporting IE < 9 though.

Using `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var newArray = otherArray.map(function(val) {
    return typeof val === 'undefined' ? myArray.shift() : val;
});
```

Be aware that this will not hit indexes that have never been set.

Using `while` loop:

```
while (myArray.length > 0) {
  var emptyIdx = otherArray.indexOf();
  otherArray[emptyIdx] = myArray.shift();
}
```

Edit: Ok, if the elements in the array are truly not set, as they are in your description, these solutions won't work since they'll skip over the unset indexes. Here's one that would work:

```js
var myArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 9];
var otherArray = [1, , 3, , 5, , 7];

var lastIdx = -1;
otherArray.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  if (idx - lastIdx > 1) {
    otherArray[idx - 1] = myArray.shift();
  }
});

if (myArray.length > 0) {
  otherArray = otherArray.concat(myArray);
}

document.body.innerHTML = otherArray;
```

Comment: So are you saying that it is impossible to `map()` this?

Comment: @CharlesWatson Yes, that's the reason why deceze has rewritten his answer ;)

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the original lists? I'm not seeing the appeal of the map function for this usage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm giving up on this. Not my day... ;)

Comment: .map has no real appeal, I just can't use for/for each, I am confident in my abilities to use a for loop

Comment: `... otherArray.map(...` will not work because it may not hit the not set elements.

Comment: @CDelaney is it a joke or all these pieces of code do not work ?

Comment: @Hacketo haaah, yes, it was a very funny joke. Thank you for being constructive.

Comment: @Hacketo That probably means one of the solutions worked for the true set of data being used, which may not have involved unset indexes, but rather undefined values. Either way, saying "is this a joke?" is patronizing and unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array and check for undefined values like:

```js
var otherArray = [1, , 3, , 5, , 7];
var myArray = [2, 4, 6];

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < otherArray.length; i++) {
    //check if a value is undefined
    if (!otherArray[i]) {
        //then change this value with the new from other array
        otherArray[i] = myArray[j];
        j++;
    }
}
console.log(otherArray);//prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursivity, this function will fill the `undefined` items of the first array with the items of the second one until it reach the end of one of the arrays used.

```js
var otherArray = [1, , 3, , 5, , 7];
var myArray = [2, 4, 6];


function fillArray(ar1, ar2, i){
    if (!i) i = 0;

    if (!ar1[i]){
        ar1[i] = ar2.shift();
    }
    if (++i < ar1.length && ar2.length > 0){
        fillArray(ar1, ar2, i);   
    }
}


fillArray(otherArray, myArray); // this will update the content of originals arrays, 
// use otherArray.slice() to get a copy.

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(otherArray);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

If you want to add elements (because there is other items in `myArray` and there is no space left in `otherArray`) you can change the condition to continue replacing the `&&` with `||`

```
if (++i < ar1.length || ar2.length > 0){
```